# separate email traffic from website traffic

Tags: http, server, email-client, web-traffic

When we click a link on a website and visit that link the HTTP request contains the previous site as the HTTP referrer. But if I click a link inside a email I have received, that HTTP request does not contain a HTTP referrer field...(clicking a link in a email received to my gmail)

So my question is, do we have a method to distinguish between these two scenarios ?

I mean any method to identify these two clicks separately using parameters in the HTTP request

Comment: can someone give me little help here ???

Comment: Use different links?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that when You click a link on a **https** page the header not contains the HTTP referrer (in php: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']). And google use https, so from links in gmail the HTTP referrer not send.

Answer (score 0):

Just like explained in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581663/serverhttp-referer-is-not-working-on-mozilla/27581765#27581765), don't rely on the referrer.

Just use a query string parameter like `&source=email`, `&fromemail=true` or `&campaign=email`.